# Android Drawable Importer not found in plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-developer-api

I am working with Android Studio and need both the *batch drawable* and the *vector drawable* plugin. However, when I open the SDK manager, these plugins do not show up in the list.

[image: plugins]

How can I install these plugins? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a repository that was Forked from the original plugin. Vincent Loi created it And is working fine in Android Studio 4 Here is the repo [android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/Vincent-Loi/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

And from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer/versions/stable) you can download the plugin.

Note from Vincent Loi:

```
This fork came about because the original package stopped working somewhere around Android Studio 3.5. I have provided an installation zip here. As at 31Jan2020 it is known to run nicely on AS 3.6 RC 1. Any feedback would be appreciated.
```

if for some reson did't work you can use [this](https://appicon.co/)

Answer (score 0):

I think they are default plugins. Go to your **res** folder, right click >> **new** and in the last, you can see that both plugins are available. 

However they don't show up in Settings >> Plugins.
[image]

Comment: No actually i didnt found over there.Firstly i tried to find in by right clicking on res and also on tried this on drawable but i didnt found that

Comment: ok. you are in marketplace tab. check installed tab. It is possible that your plugin is not enabled.